# Do there exist any published security audits of FreeOTFE?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption

I see that http://www.freeotfe.org offers FOSS encryption software for Windows. This software also has [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeOTFE) devoted to it.

However, it appears to have received less scrutiny than its competitors. I would like to know what independent scrutiny it has received (if any); and whether there are any other reasons it should be considered reliable (or not).

Comment: I believe TrueCrypt is free - if you're worried about a program without a lot of documentation, use something that has actually been put to the test.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of TrueCrypt and strongly dislike its license.